# Video played using AVPlayer disappears from its container view in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am playing a video using AVPlayer. I use addSubLayer method of CALayer on a UIView on which I want to play the video. Everything works fine but when I send App in background and then again bring App back in foreground the video disappears(Video duration is just 1 second). Until I send App in background, the video(even though it was finished playing) stays on the container view and we can see it. But as soon as I do background and then foreground of App, video/may be the layer disappears.

Would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep last frame of your video to stay on container view when you bring your app to foreground.

Please set `actionAtItemEnd` property of AVPlayer object with

`AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.pause` option. This will pause the video when the player finishes playing the video and keep the layer on your container view.

Answer (score -1):

Please set Observer for Application Background/Foreground. When your app came from Background to Foreground then in your Observer method insert below code.

```
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)
```